# Dropdown validation in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to validate the dropdown list in MVC 5 .But it's not working.
Below is my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text ="Male", Value="Male" },
            new SelectListItem {Text ="Female", Value="Female" }
        },
        "Select Gender")
```

In my Model, i have specified this field as required. But it still not working.
Below is my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Gender.")]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Required Attribute not working in asp net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734608/required-attribute-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the client to validate before making the post, first you need to make sure `UnobtrusiveJavascript` is enabled in your `Web.Config`. Check if     `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is set to true.

If you are making an ajax request, you need to validate the form explicity like:

```
 var $form = ('#myForm');
 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
 if ($form.valid())
 {
    // continue with the POST
 }
```