# Validation many to many relationship ef core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, ef-core-2.0

I want to know if there's a way to add a validator where an author needs to be selected on a combobox otherwise it will display an error.

In my application I have three models, Books, Authors and the join table Rel_Book_Author.

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    [Column("book_id")]
    public int book_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [Column("liv_title")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Every book needs a title")]
    public string liv_title { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    [Column("aut_id")]
    public int aut_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Author's Name")]
    [Column("aut_name")]
    public string aut_name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Rel_Book_Author> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}

public class Rel_Book_Author
{
    [Column("hla_aut_id")]
    public int aut_id { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }

    [Column("hla_book_id")]
    public int book_id { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What validation?

Comment: Do you mean to validate data model properties?
Maybe this answer helps, from [tomRedox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426175/entity-framework-core-doesnt-validate-data-when-saving#answers-header) on a maybe similar question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke edited the question. The validation is to display an error message whenever an user didn't select a author on a combobox

Comment: On what combobox? (you have not shown you view, or even what the model in the view is). But I assume its for `Rel_Book_Author`, and if you binding to `aut_id`, then add a `[Required]` attribute to that property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption here that your view's model will be the `Rel_Book_Author` class, or a list of those classes, and so you the view shows a book (or books) and allows the user to pick the author from a list for each book?

If so, then validation should work [as per any other model with data annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

EF Core [does not perform any validations itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43427057/1879019), it expects you to do have already validated the object using the [client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#client-side-validation) and on the server (typically in the controller), so the fact that the objects are related by a particular type of relationship (e.g. many-to-many) doesn't matter here.

There is [one gotcha to watch out for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48538046/1879019) with the `Required` attribute for an integer; which is that a non-nullable integer (obviously) cannot be null, it will just default to zero, which means that setting `Required` won't actually ever return a validation error for an integer in a select list (as the property will always have a value of zero or the value of whatever is selected in the list).

To get round that, declare the `aut_id` property as nullable (`int?`):

```
[Required]
public int? aut_id { get; set; }
```

or add a `Range` attribute, e.g.

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
public int? aut_id { get; set; }
```